# How do you access a friend's Minecraft world when they're offline?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am on Minecraft playing on my friend's world (not server). However, they aren't online. I want to continue my work on that world and not start brand new on survival again. I've already made a lot of progress and would not like to lose it. How can I access the world?

Comment: Try getting them to upload the world to a file sharing service (dropbox, mediafire, mega, etc) so you can play on it locally.

Comment: This question should not be downvoted. It may be true that this sounds quite absurd to an experienced Java player, but it is not a bad question.

Answer (score 3):

The world has to be hosted somewhere in order for you to access it. Your friend would either have to keep their computer on or rent a server from a Minecraft server host.

Answer (score 1):

You can do one of the following:

- Have your friend leave their device on and run Minecraft opened to LAN.
- Have your friend keep their device on and run a dedicated Server (host device must be compatible with Java), and keep in the server needs to be running all the time you want to access it.
- Purchase a Realms subscription (only the Realm owner needs a subscription).
- Rent a server from a Minecraft server hosting company (these are unofficial, so be wise in your decision).
- Rent a VPS server and manually set up a dedicated server.