# Is there any way I can join my friends world when they are offline?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Me and my friend have a world that we have been playing on for awhile. If I want to play on the world he has to be online because he made the world. Is there any way to allow me into the world when he is offline?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How Do You Access A Friends Minecraft World When They're Offline?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/368410/how-do-you-access-a-friends-minecraft-world-when-theyre-offline/368413#368413)

Answer (score 0):

Use a realm. Two player realms cost $3.99 per month, and 10 player realms cost $7.99 per month but you also get 50+ marketplace packs with it. You can get one at https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/realms-plus.